# laravel eager load - can't access model attributes

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to eagerly load a relationship:

```
Album::with('songs')->where('album_id', $albumId)->first();
```

I have this relationship in Album:

```
public function songs() {
    return $this->hasMany('Song')->where('rect_id', $this->mes_rect_id);    
}
```

but it seems that $this->mes_rect_id (this is an additional column) is totally undefined. how come?

Answer (score 0):

Your relation needs to be

```
return $this->hasMany('Song', 'rect_id', 'mes_rect_id');
```

`hasMany()` (and all other relation methods) already have support for supplying local and foreign keys for your relation. When eager loading, the relation gets accessed before the attributes of your model are loaded yet, so you can't use `$this->mes_rect_id` in your where constraint.